# SQL column to be formatted

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two columns in MySQL with `gpscoordinatelatitude` and `gpscoordinatelongitude`, both as `nvarchar`.  I have different formats for them, like:

```
GPS Coordinates
N 24 34.124 E 46 38 25.3
N 24 34.7 E 46 33.353
N 24 34.756 E 46 33.594
N 24 34.756 E 46 33.594
```

I want them in a single format, like

```
N XX XX XX.XXX E XX XX XX.XXX
```

Can any one help me to add zeroes wherever I have a single digit after the decimal point?

Answer (score 1):

Since your coordinates (like `N XX XX XX.XXX`) have a fixed length of 14:

```
UPDATE gps_table 
SET gpscoordinatelatitude = RPAD(TRIM(gpscoordinatelatitude),14,'0'),
    gpscoordinatelongitude = RPAD(TRIM(gpscoordinatelongitude),14,'0');
-- turns N 24 34.7 into N 24 34.700 and
-- turns E 46 33.5 into E 46 33.500
```

Comment: i am using sql server and the gpscoordinatelatitude and longitude are Nvarchar type .

Comment: when i run the query i am getting the error message as "'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name." the gpscooordinates are of nvarchar type.

Comment: And also "'RPAD' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL, and states "I have two columns in MySQL." Now, you change and say you're using SQL Server. SQL Server doesn't have the functions I've used -- google for substitutes.